# Unable to insert ContentVersion record in future method in apex

Tags: apex, community, contentversion

In a partner Community, I am inserting a ContentVersion record before doing future callout and also inserting ContentVersion record within future callout .

I am able to insert ContentVersion record before future callout successfully, but within Fututre callout It is giving error -

*System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.: [NetworkId]*

```
public class myclass
{
....
insert ContentVersion1; // Able to insert record
callout();
}

@future(callout = true)
callout(){
...
insert ContentVersion2; // Gives error *System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.: [NetworkId]*
}
```

Not sure why ContentVersion version record is not inserted in future callout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetworkId is required to be filled out when doing inserts on ContentVersion documents when communities are enabled and in a community context. I have seen similar issues in the past where If NetworkId doesn't exist, the insert fails with the following error INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

Here is what the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_network.htm) says:

> All users with a content feature license can create versions in their
> personal library. Customer and Partner Portal users must also supply
> the NetworkId of the community in the request.

You can add debug statements to check the value of the network id to see if it is returning a null value. You can do so by using getNetworkId()

**getNetworkId()**

Returns the user’s current community.

**Signature**

public static String getNetworkId()

**Return Value**

Type: String

I have also seen issues in the past where @future method is not able to get the context of the NetworkId for the contentversion record. When inserting a ContentVersion and then a ContentDocumentLink as a Partner Communities user, the Network Id is correctly set on the ContentVersion. However, if that logic is executed asynchronously, such as in a @future method, then the Network Id is no longer present (confirmed by debugging out Network.getNetworkId() in both sync and async logic) and the ContentDocument insert fails with the message INSUFFICIENT ACCESS RIGHTS ON CROSS-REFERENCE ENTITY (NetworkId).

A potential fix is to pass the networkId value externally to the contentversion in such scenarios. See sample code below

```
public static void methodCall(){
String netId = network.getNetworkId();
dummyFutureCall('0010I00002GitdvQAB',netId);
}

@future
public static void dummyFutureCall(Id BasketId,String netValue){
system.debug('**networkId In method : ' + network.getNetworkId());
system.debug('**networkId In method : ' + netValue);
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
cv.Title = 'Test Document';
cv.PathOnClient = 'TestDocument.pdf';
cv.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content');
cv.IsMajorVersion = true;
cv.NetworkId = netValue;
Insert cv;
//Get Content Documents
List<ContentVersion> docList = [SELECT Id, contentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion where id =: cv.id ];

//Create ContentDocumentLink
ContentDocumentLink cdl = New ContentDocumentLink();
cdl.LinkedEntityId = basketId;
cdl.ContentDocumentId = docList[0].contentDocumentId;
cdl.shareType = 'V';
Insert cdl;
}
```

Comment: Its working now.. Thank you so much!